# How to reflect an oracle database with BINARY_DOUBLE type columns

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I tried to reflect an existing oracle database into sqlalchemy metadata:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table

db_uri = 'oracle://USER:PASS@MYDBTNSNAME'
engine = create_engine(db_uri)

# create a MetaData instance
metadata = MetaData()

# reflect db schema to MetaData
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
```

This returns the following:

```
SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'BINARY_DOUBLE' of column 'column_1'(coltype, colname))
```

I have tried to import native types and also the types from dialect oracle using

```
from sqlalchemy.types import *
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import *
```

but it seems it does not recognize `BINARY_DOUBLE` type

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b69d481f6a4e> in <module>()
      1 from sqlalchemy.types import *
----> 2 from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import *

AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle' has no attribute 'BINARY_DOUBLE'
```

I am using SQLAlchemy, version '1.2.1'

Comment: Probably you need [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/lqfaofbWc30). Which mentioned the fix as `from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.base import ischema_names` and `ischema_names['BINARY_DOUBLE'] = OracleBinaryDouble` this

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried it. If I didn't miss anything, it only maps the column type to `NullType()` after applying `metadata.reflect()` function. I need to map it to something like http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.NATIVE_FLOAT

Comment: Unfortunately don't have oracle to test and debug what it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in sqlalchemy [changelog](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_12.html#change-1.2.8-oracle), this functionality has been included in version 1.2.8:

```
[oracle] [bug] Added reflection capabilities for the oracle.BINARY_FLOAT, oracle.BINARY_DOUBLE datatypes
```

I have checked it using 1.2.18 version and now reflection works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overriding the default mapping relfection in your db? Like so

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.base import BINARY_DOUBLE

group_table = sa.Table('groups', metadata,
    sa.Column('your_column', BINARY_DOUBLE(asdecimal=True)),
    autoload=True,
    include_columns=[
    'your_column',
    '...'
    ],
)
```

Or just importing that `BINARY_DOBULE` from `sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.base`

I'd ask that in a comment, but I can't do so as I just joined.

Comment: Just importing `BINARY_DOUBLE` from `sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.base` does assign `NullType()` when using `metadata.reflect(bind=engine)`. Therefore, it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a column type that is not well supported by sqlalchemy / DB driver. So avoid that type.

Create a view as (roughly) SELECT * FROM base_table, with the minor tweak of casting binary double columns to a more convenient numeric type. Then reflect the view.

Comment: I cannot change the database schema. My question is how to make SQLAlchemy handle BINARY_DOUBLE